# Dynamic Role Level Secuirty SSAS Mutildimensional Group using Active Directory Group

Tags: database, ssas, mdx

Implement RLS on SSAS Multidimensional Cube using User Group (not individuals Users)

I have created the SSAS multidimensional and implemented the Row level security on users. Is there any way to implement row level using User Groups(the Group has a list of all users)? not individual users.